# How to compute the longest common subsequence of two equal length strings in O((L+1)n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, space-complexity

If I have two equal length strings, A and B, which are both of length n and have a longest common subsequence (LCS(A,B)) of length (n - L), how can I compute L in O((L+1)n) time while using only O(L+1) space? (Assuming that the space needed to store A and B isn't counted).

I've been trying to consult research articles to figure out how to do this, but to no avail. Any help towards figuring out how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. I know it is possible because I used to have the source code to do it from a third party, but now need to reimplement it in a different environment.

Comment: Is it really possible to not pay the o(n^2) time without accepting o(n) space? Anyway, have you looked at suffix trees?